# win32com (Python): Adding same hyperlink to multiple instances of the same text in Microsoft Word

Tags: python, win32com, python-docx

I am using win32com in Python to add hyperlinks to a document. In rare instances, there is a piece of text that appears more than once, and thus needs to be hyperlinked more than once. It's my understanding that `.Hyperlinks.Add()` is "lazy" and only hyperlinks the first instance found. I'm wondering if there is a way to hyperlink all instances, perhaps by dynamically shifting the range, where each new range begins where the last instance of the text ended? Or maybe there is a simpler way? The code I have been using is below. Thanks for your help.

```
import win32com.client
from os import path

for link_text in hyperlink_dict:
        wordapp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
        wordapp.Documents.Open(os.path.join(save_folder, doc_version))
        doc = wordapp.ActiveDocument
        doc_range = doc.Range()
        docText = doc.Content.text

        if wordapp.Selection.Find.Execute(FindText=link_text) == True:
            doc_range.Hyperlinks.Add(Anchor=wordapp.Selection.Range, Address=hyperlink_dict[link_text])
```

Comment: ".Hyperlinks.Add() is "lazy" -- no it is not lazy; it does what it is supposed to do. But you do need to loop your call to `.Find.Execute` then call `.Hyperlinks.Add()` again.

Comment: Thanks!

I changed `if wordapp.Selection.Find.Execute(FindText=link_text) == True:` to `while wordapp.Selection.Find.Execute(FindText=link_text) == True:` and it seems to work now.

Also, I didn't mean "lazy" as a pejorative :) I had seen it referenced this way elsewhere that seemed authoritative, so I mimicked it. Lesson learned...